# Extract metadata from Word files sent anonymously

Tags: microsoft-word, dropbox, metadata, onedrive

I am being sent numerous explicit/harassing Word files via Skydrive and was wondering if there is a method of extracting and viewing the metadata or any useful identifying information after downloading.

Comment: It can be viewed if they did not delete it. Note: A skilled hacker can forge this information easily.

Comment: This is how they caught the BTK killer.

Answer (score 0):

Phil Harvey's [EXIFTool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) can display the EXIF tags of any supported file. But, as mentioned by @Cybernard, the information can be easily removed/modified using tools such as this.

I'm not a lawyer, but as explained by the US Department of Justice's [Cybercrime page](http://www.justice.gov/criminal/cybercrime/reporting.html), you should contact your local, state and federal law enforcement agencies to assist you with the issue you're experiencing. Or consult a lawyer whom specializes in Cybercrime victims.